# Passing an env. variable dynamically to Application module, at runtime?

Tags: elixir, ecto, erlang-otp, gen-server

In my opt application I have some stuff that gets run on application boot:

```
    defmodule MyApp.Application do
      use Application

      def start(_type, _args) do
        children = [
          {Phoenix.PubSub, [name: MyApp.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]},
          {MyAppLib.Repo, []},
          {MyAppWeb.Endpoint, []},
          {MyAppLib.Cache, []},


          # these are GenServer-s, some may work with a database

          {MyApp.Worker1, []},      # 1 
          {MyApp.Worker2, []},      # 2
          {MyApp.Initializer, []}   # 3

        ]

        opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
        Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
      end
```

However, I've found out that whenever I deploy the app on a new server, it'll fail to start up because a database hasn't been created yet. And even starting the application via console won't solve the problem because it'll still crash due to the same reason.

How to fix it?

---

Should I introduce a boolean env. variable "disable_db_related_workers" which I'd set to 'true' only when running the app the first time on a new server? Then I'd run console and from it I'd run the migrations.

```
$ MIX_ENV=prod DISABLE_DB_WORKERS=true ~/my_apps/my_app1/bin/my_app1 console
```

If so, how to do this properly inside `Application` then? It'll have to be evaluated at runtime, that is, not at compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Ecto.Migrator.up/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html#up/4) is your friend.

It might be called from `Application.start/2` directly because it’s idempotent. It might be called *before* starting the application right after deploy.

Besides this advice, the real implementation is actually a matter of taste.

Comment: I already have a module that runs migrations, and it's one of those 'workers' mentioned in the code. That is, where in Application will it have to be called from precisely then? As the 1st command in `start(_type, _args)`?

Comment: Before starting Repo. First line works, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help when the database is not created, we have a server that uses repo.__adapter__.storage_up/1, but I go usually with creating database manually.

Comment: @Daniel the question explicitly stated the issue is with migrations. But yes, generally your comment makes total sense.